# Finding k-order statistics among unknowns

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, optimization, algorithms

Let there be $x^2$ horses, at a time we can compare $x$ of them and establish the order of speed between them. For what is the smallest comparison you can find the $x+1$ speed horse?

I will be glad to any help, thanks!

Comment: I came up with a problem based on the idea of a well-known problem, I have a hypothesis that the answer is $x+3$, but I don’t know how to prove it.

Comment: What is your algorithm for doing it in $x+3$ $x$-way comparisons?

Comment: I do not have an exact algorithm, but I have some thoughts about the first steps.If you are interested, I can write ...

Comment: Yes, I'm interested.  Please indicate your ideas.